# how to use an already generated tagfile with opengrok.jar in windows

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags, opengrok

I have downloaded and extracted opengrok in localsystem and have ctags.exe in the local system

I tried to execute the following command with those arguments and got the following response pasted below the linebreak.

> java -jar opengrok.jar -W d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\configuration.xml  -P
>   -S -v -s d:\Projects\codebase -d d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\grokdata  -c d:\ctags\ctags.exe

---

> D:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\lib>java -jar opengrok.jar -W
>   d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\configuration.xml  -P -S -v -s
>   d:\Projects\codebase -d d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\grokdata  -c
>   d:\ctags\ctags.exe Nov 28, 2018 7:23:52 PM
>   org.opengrok.indexer.index.Indexer parseOptions INFO: Indexer options:
>   [-W, d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\configuration.xml, -P, -S, -v, -s,
>   d:\Projects\codebase, -d, d:\opengrok-1.1-rc41\grokdata, -c,
>   d:\ctags\ctags.exe] Logging filehandler pattern: %h/java%u.log Nov 28,
>   2018 7:23:52 PM org.opengrok.indexer.index.Indexer main INFO: Indexer
>   version 1.1-rc41 (fd2e8feba888a0b3c6938be7544aca3502695940) Nov 28,
>   2018 7:23:52 PM org.opengrok.indexer.configuration.RuntimeEnvironment
>   validateUniversalCtags SEVERE: Error: No Universal Ctags found !
>   (tried running d:\ctags\ctags.exe) Please use the -c option to specify
>   path to a Universal Ctags program. Or set it in Java system property
>   org.opengrok.indexer.analysis.Ctags Nov 28, 2018 7:23:52 PM
>   org.opengrok.indexer.index.Indexer main SEVERE: Exception running
>   indexer org.opengrok.indexer.index.IndexerException: Didn't find
>   Universal Ctags
>           at org.opengrok.indexer.index.Indexer.prepareIndexer(Indexer.java:888)
>           at org.opengrok.indexer.index.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:298)
>
> Usage: java -jar opengrok.jar [options] [subDir1 [...]]

So, i executed [d:\ctags\ctags.exe -R -f d:\tagfile.txt] directly in the d:\projects\codebase fodler and got the tag file.

In this case how do i use an already indexed/tagged file(tagfile.txt) with opengrok ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you the [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) installed?

The OpenGrok 1.1 requires the Universal Ctags accordingly with the [Release Notes](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/releases/tag/1.1).

Comment: It is exuberant ctags version 58

Comment: Uhm... you're using the OpenGrok 1.1 which requires Universal Ctags... I just updated the answer.